# XWPF POI draw vertical line in left of text paragraph

Tags: apache-poi, line, drawing, paragraph, xwpf

how draw vertical line in left of text paragraph with xwpf poi
and add diagonal line in top and bottom of every page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T1Uc.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried? The lines at left of the paragraphs seems to be left border lines ([XWPFParagraph.setBorderLeft](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html#setBorderLeft-org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.Borders-)).

Comment: ok but, i mean thats....i will upload document to my app and my app automatically draw line in that document....

Comment: and i will change the line color to red

Comment: please, help me

Comment: Posting a requirement and then getting the code to fulfill that requirement ist not how this site works. Make an effort, post your code, tell what is not working using your code. Then one can help you. Else not.

Comment: i have code for my question yet.